# jquery masonry images are overlapping until a page resize is done

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, jquery-masonry

I've found this template that demonstrates the issue I'm having with [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and image layout. Take a look at this twitter bootstrap template [page](http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB0F35928/gallery.html):

The very first time the page is loaded all the images are stacked on each other until a page refresh or re-size is done.  The images are then displayed correctly.

Here is my HTML and jQuery that has the same problem:

### HTML

```
<div class="gallery-masonry masonry" style="position: relative; min-height:100px; height: auto;">
  <div id="loading">Loading ...</div>                            
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$.post("functions/photo_functions.php", { f: 'getallphotos'}, function(data) {

  $('#loading').hide();

    if(data) {  
      $.each(data.images, function(i, image) {
        var img_block = '<div class="item masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">' +
        '<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="'+image.url+'" alt=""></a>' +
        '<div class="actions">' +
        '<a title="" href="#" class="tip-top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i></a>' +
        '<a title="" href="#" class="tip-top" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

        $(".gallery-masonry").append(img_block);
          });

        $('.gallery-masonry').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          isAnimated: true,
          isFitWidth: true
        });             
      }

    }, "json");
```

Any idea why this is happening and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use imagesLoaded() to triggered masonry after all images are loaded.
(`imagesLoaded()` is provided by the script http://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded.)

```
$('.gallery-masonry').imagesLoaded( function(){
  $('.gallery-masonry').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.item',
   isAnimated: true,
   isFitWidth: true
  });
});
```

Comment: imagesLoaded() is provided by the script https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded. One needs to integrate this as well.

Comment: THANK YOU. I have just normal Jquery. You can see this exact code running on www.BitPixr.com now. Fixed the nasty looking home page for new users. THX.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer has missing steps. So here is a step-by-step.

1. Go to the [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) repo and download the minified version at https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/blob/master/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js.
2. Add that library to your project.
3. At the bottom of your page call the file

```[Adjust path to your javascript files]

```
<script src="/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('.gallery-masonry').imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('.gallery-masonry').masonry({
     itemSelector: '.item',
     isAnimated: true,
     isFitWidth: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ^^^^^ This guy is right. You need to load in the images loaded package. It's very simple.